# Error loading third party js library

Tags: javascript, lightning-web-components

Just trying to load a js library in a LWC. Cannot even get the thing to load. I just want it to load and do nothing.

Static resource here:

```
Name headerConfig
Namespace Prefix    
Description 
MIME Type   text/javascript
Cache Control   Private
Size    615 bytes
```

```
import { LightningElement } from 'lwc';
import { ShowToastEvent } from 'lightning/platformShowToastEvent';
import { loadScript, loadStyle } from 'lightning/platformResourceLoader';
import headerConfig from '@salesforce/resourceUrl/headerConfig';


export default class UtahHeader extends LightningElement {

error;
successMessage = '';
utahHeaderInit = false;

renderedCallback() {
    
    // if(this.utahHeaderInit) {
    //     return;
    // }

    // this.utahHeaderInit = true;
    Promise.all([
    loadScript(this, headerConfig)
    ])
    
    .then(() => {
        this.error = undefined;
        this.showSuccessMessage();
        alert('loaded');
        // this.loadConfig();
        // this.loadMainMenu();
    })
    .catch(error => {
        this.error = error;
        this.dispatchEvent(
            new ShowToastEvent({
                title: 'Errrorrr',
                variant: 'error',
            }),
        );
    });
}

showSuccessMessage() {
    this.successMessage = 'loaded succ';
    alert('scripts loaded succ');
}
```

```
    <template>
    <lightning-card title="Third Party Library Demo" icon-name="custom:custom19">
        <p><b style="color:blue;">{successMessage}</b></p>
    </lightning-card>
</template>

Any ideas what I'm doing wrong here? Tried to follow other posts but I'm able to rectify mine.. if I try to add error.message, it says it's an undefined property so I can't even find out what the issue is.
```

Answer (score 0):

Nvm, seems like a problem with the external library itself. React loads fine.

Comment: Do you have a link to the 3rd party library (so I can download and try it)?